# Angular2 check for input change

Tags: angular

Edited with more code:

I'm simply trying to update an input, then submit the form. But when I get the form via server side code it has not been updated.

```
<form id="cardsForm" method="post">
        <input id="jsonSearchCards" name="jsonSearchCards" type="text" value="{{cardsSQL}}">
    </form>
<a class="cardIcon" (click)="OpenDispatchView()" title="Testing"><span class="icon-file-text2"></span>

OpenDispatchView(): void {
    var url = 'Users/Cards';
    var dto = someJson;
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(dto);

    this.cardsSQL = jsonData;

    $('#cardsForm').attr('action', GlobalVariables.SITE_ROOT + 'Users/Cards/').submit();

}
```

I think it's because angular doesn't populate value, but ng-reflect-value??

Comment: Programmatically how? Why don't you call `doSomething()` directly when you modify the input programmatically?

Comment: Well, because I'm trying to populate the input then submit a form. But there's problems with timing. The input is not populated when the form submits. So i wanted to detect change, then submit the form.

Comment: Please provide more information about you modify it programmatically.

Comment: I edited it some, does that make sense?

Comment: I don't get why you expect the input to update. The code doesn't touch the input. What value should it be updated with?

Comment: it changes cardSQL which is what the input is bound to. How should I do it?

Comment: do you have another field in your form that change ? if that's the case, you can leverage that event to do what you want. You can even execute  `doSomething()` before submitting the form.

Comment: @mickdev, no i don't

Comment: So if you have to wait server response before submitting why don't you do it when the Promise/Observable resolve ? Can you update your question and provide the method that call the server before submit?

Comment: edited again, with more code. Understand what I'm trying to do now?

Comment: I still don't get why you think the input should be updated. What statement is supposed to update the input, and to what value?

Comment: look at the value of the input. Then i do this this.cardsSQL = jsonData;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I get it now. Try this :

```
//template
<form id="cardsForm" method="post">
        <input id="jsonSearchCards" name="jsonSearchCards" type="text" value="{{cardsSQL}}" #input>
</form>

//component
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('input') input;
OpenDispatchView(): void {
    var url = 'Users/Cards';
    var dto = someJson;
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(dto);

    this.input.nativeElement.value = jsonData; //this should work

    $('#cardsForm').attr('action', GlobalVariables.SITE_ROOT + 'Users/Cards/').submit(); //but I don't know about this.

}
```

To be honest, I don't think you need a form for this...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a form, I would change that and make it a bit more "angular-ish".

```
<form #cardsForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(cardsForm.value)">
   <input name="jsonSearchCards" type="text" value="{{cardsSQL}}" [(ngModel)]="cardsSQL">
</form>
```

And when you submit your form, you have a nice object to work with with the above `submitForm` method:

```
{
  "jsonSearchCards": "the value"
}
```

.. with which you can make your http-request to submit the form.

This should work fine, here's a

### **[demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BhwXTzQskbfKsfcHbbyI?p=preview)**

Hope this helps!